# Rollback an entire block while executing the rest in plsql

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, rollback

I have a package which is executing different inserts and updates for job position and location tables.Something like :

```
Create or replace package body pack_name 
as 
procedure proc
as

----Posistion Block

Begin

  Begin

  insert into xx_pos_table
  select * 
  from xx_i_pos_table;

  exception when others then
  end;

  Begin

  insert into xx_pos_tl_table
  select * from xx_i_pos_tl_table;

  exception when others then
  end;

  Begin

  Update xx_pos_extra
  set err_msg =Null

  exception when others then
  end;

end;

---Job block
   Begin

  Update xx_job_extra
  set err_msg =Null

  exception when others then
  end;

-- Loc block
   Begin

  Update xx_loc_extra
  set err_msg =Null

  exception when others then
  end;
end;
end;
```

Now i want that if in position block for example there is an error while insertin data in xx_pos_extra then only position block should be rolled back and data from xx_pos_table,xx_pos_tl_table and xx_pos_extra should not be entered. But the rest of the blocks (Job and location)should be executed.

Comment: i haven't got you. You said that *data from xx_pos_table,xx_pos_tl_table and xx_pos_extra should not be entered* and at the same time *But the rest of the blocks should be executed*. Are the `xx_pos_tl_table` and `xx_pos_extra` inserts not the *rest of the blocks*?

Comment: @agent5566-Thanks for rectifyin... i have edited my question.I mean job and position block should be executed xx_job_extra and xx_location should be updated

Comment: You should just wrap your position block in `SAVEPOINT` and rollback to it in exception block

Comment: @agent5566- Okay... trying to understand Savepoint concept. Will let you know if this works :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a savepoint to [rollback to](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/sqloperations.htm#BABGAAIG) if an exception occurs like this:

```
---Job block

  begin
  SAVEPOINT p_rollback;
      Update xx_job_extra
      set err_msg =Null

  exception when others then
      rollback to p_rollback;
  end;

-- Loc block
```